# Converting a list of weeks to a dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert this list of weeks in a year to dates in Python and then into a Pandas column but having weird results:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

week = [25,31]
year = 2021
dates = []
for i in week:
   date = datetime.date(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weeks=+i)
   dates.append(date)
print(dates)
```

The printout of the dates looks like this:

```
[datetime.date(2021, 6, 25), datetime.date(2021, 8, 6)]
```

i need it to look like this [ 2021-06-25, 2021-08-06]
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think that's a weird result?  The 25th week started 25 June 2021.  Did you think you were creating a `range`?  Your list has exactly two weeks in it.  Did you want `week = list(range(25,32))`?

Comment: That output is correct, it makes perfect sense for your narrative and the program you shared. In particular, it definitely does not look "weird". If you had _different_ desired output in mind, be explicit, please include it within the question. What are you aiming for? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Did you maybe want to import `pandas` as part of your code?

Comment: Maybe there is a misconception here between a *week offset* (as you have it in your code) and a calendar week, as for instance in the [iso week date](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)?

Comment: i just need it to look like a list of dates - [2021-06-25, 2021-08-06]

Answer (score 0):

import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
dates = []
for i in week:
date = datetime.date(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weeks=+i)
dates.append(date)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dates)